# ReSharper cannot decompile .NET Standard assemblies

Tags: c#, resharper

I have just changed the project type to Portable in VisualStudio 2015. But it seems that ReSharper cannot decompile the standard .NET libraries anymore.

It just displays empty bodies with default return values:
[image]

I know that the exact implementation of the .NET Standard may differ on the different platforms. But still it would be useful to see at least the Windows version of the standard libraries without explicitly visiting the reference sources site or using a DotPeek or similar tool.

Can I somehow configure ReSharper to decompile one of the actual implementations (eg. Windows version) if project type is Portable?

Comment: I'm not a legal expert but does the license agreement for ReSharper allow you to then post a copy of reverse-engineered source code for assemblies it has decompiled?

Comment: @MickyD: I am just talking about the official Microsoft sources, which are btw available on referencesource.microsoft.com. The decompilation of other 3rd parties still work with no problem. So my question is just a convenience problem.

Comment: If you take a look at the size of the files that are present in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile111`, it is highly improbable that they contain "real" code... *mscorlib.dll* is 38kb!

Comment: @xanatos: Yes, and that's why I asked "Can I somehow configure ReSharper to decompile *one of the actual implementations*"

Comment: @MickyD: This is a fallback mechanism. It tries to download the sources in the first place. If it fails, goes on with decompilation. If project type is one of the normal .NET Frameworks download usually succeeds.

Comment: What version of ReSharper are you using? Can you try ReSharper 2017.1, which has just been released? It should hopefully know how to resolve the reference assembly to the actual implementation assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Mind the file path please.

Reference assemblies in such folders are just for reference purposes, and that's why even a decompiler can only show you the API surface.

You might read the Roslyn thread for technical details,

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/2184

Comment: I know they are just "placeholder" assemblies. That's why I asked _"Can I somehow configure ReSharper to decompile one of the actual implementations (eg. Windows version) if project type is Portable?"_

Comment: @taffer how to map reference assemblies to runtime assemblies is a bigger thing than your imagination, and I don't think JetBrains has that implemented yet.